# Docker Flask - jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound error

Tags: python, docker, flask

The site loads fine outside the Docker container. I've looked through the other postings and I've tried their solutions but they aren't working for me.

I'm running Windows 7 and the Docker Quickstart Terminal. I'm using the `192.168.99.100` IP to access the site.

My directory structure is:

```
- static
    - style.css
- templates
    - index.html
- app.py
- Dockerfile
- requirements.txt
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.5

EXPOSE 5000

RUN mkdir -p /app

COPY static /app
COPY templates /app
COPY app.py /app
COPY requirements.txt /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
```

My docker commands are:

```
docker build -t "web-app" -f ./Dockerfile .
docker run -p 5000:5000 "web-app"
```

Trying to access the site `http://192.168.99.100:5000/` gives me the error `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `RUN ls /app` to your `Dockerfile`. I believe you'll find that `COPY templates /app` is copying the contents of `templates` to `/app`, instead of copying the directory itself.

You can solve the problem by changing your `Dockerfile` to:

```
COPY static /app/static
COPY templates /app/templates
COPY app.py /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
```

Alternatively you can change your layout to:

```
- app
  - static
      - style.css
  - templates
      - index.html
  - app.py
  - requirements.txt
- Dockerfile
```

and then your `COPY` commands simplify to:

```
COPY app /app
```

Comment: That was it. It wasn't copying the directories, just the contents of the directories.

Answer (score 1):

From Flask docs:

> Flask will look for templates in the templates folder. So if your application is a module, this folder is next to that module, if it’s a package it’s actually inside your package:
>
> Case 1: a module:

```
/application.py
/templates
    /hello.html
```

> Case 2: a package:

```
/application
    /__init__.py
    /templates
        /hello.html
```

If your application is in a package (case 2), you will need to include an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it ended up not being the solution I needed though.